# How to return data with Laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I have problem with method AjaxController::InsertComment($comment,$name); not return $id variable into my ajax.bade.php.
It insert data into database correctly but not return...

Here is my Ajax Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AjaxController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('ajax.ajax');
    }

    public static function InsertComment($comment,$name){

        $qv = DB::table('comments')->insert(                        
                      array(
                        'name'   => $name,
                        'comments_text' => $comment
                        )
                    );

        //$id = DB::table('comments')->insertGetId(array('name' => 'john@example.com', 'comments_text' => 'asdasdsa'));

        $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();


        return $id;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got you now. Suppose we have the following:

`Example:  ajax.blade.php`

```
<div>{{ "Hi" }} </div>
    <script>
    $.post('/ajax', {
        '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
        task: "comment_insert",
        userID: _userID,
        comment: _comment,
        name: _name,
        userName: _userName,
        date: _date
    }).done(function( data ) {
        alert( "ID Loaded: " + data );
    });
</script>
```

Your controller should read like:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AjaxController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('ajax.ajax');
    }

    public static function InsertComment($comment,$name)
    {
        $id = DB::table('comments')
                    ->insertGetId(array(
                        'name'   => $name,
                        'comments_text' => $comment
                    ));
        return $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can I this {{ $id }} add to my php file? something like this: $std -> comment_id = {{ $id }} ;

Comment: Can you rephrase that? I'm not sure I understand that last question?

Comment: If you're using an `ajax.blade.php` which I'm assuming you're using, then you can echo the `$id` in your template like so: 

        ``<html>
            <body>
                <h1>Hello!</h1>
                {{ isset($id) ? $id : 'no id was passed' }}
            </body>
        </html>``

Comment: I using ajax.blade.php to recive post data from jQuery script and send back, so I need from AjaxController to return data to ajax.blade.php so I can manipute to that data trought ajax.blade.php script

Comment: see my last edit above, the key is in ```$id = DB::table('comments')->insertGetId( [..] );```

Comment: Here is my jQuery post req: $.post('/ajax',
                {
                    '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
                    task: "comment_insert",
                    userID: _userID,
                    comment: _comment,
                    name: _name,
                    userName: _userName,
                    date: _date
                }

Comment: can you also post you ``Router::`` routes?